# How to remove (widget-sidebar-navbar-footer) blogspot (Blgger) Template

Tags: javascript, html, css, templates, blogger

simply I like a blogger template Name: Essential
but I want to:-

**remove :**

1. Sidebar
2. Header
3. Navbar
4. Footer
5. Menu

with thier styles, scripts and meta

**kEEP:**

1. Post
2. Post Content
3. Static Page

with their styles, scripts and meta

I tried more but I could not. this is the template I am talking about I insert URL because I could not insert full xml code here

1. **https://basbabbas.blogspot.com/**
2. **`Template here https://pastebin.com/md59EaXj`**

if you not understand my question tell me and will explain. but as I said above I want every thing in this template remove except pot post content and static page with their style .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add these styles to your CSS to hide them:

```
header, aside, footer, .centered-top-placeholder.cloned {
    display: none;
}
```

It should work. If you have access and the knowledge editing the template to remove the DOM element is the best practice.

Comment: Are there other ways? Can we remove them by deleting <b:section or <b:widget . So that I get a clean template. I know this is easy for you. But it is very difficult for me. I wish I knew it I wish we did.
Template here https://pastebin.com/md59EaXj

Comment: You can figure it out by removing different sections on a dev environment and finding out the sections but the link on your comment is not good enough to clearly say what should be done.